# How to resolve the same dependency between a child and parent class with structuremap

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I have a couple classes that look like this

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass(IChildClass childClass, IDependency dependency)
    { }
}

public ChildClass : IChildClass
{
    public ParentClass(IDependency dependency)
    { }
}
```

Is there a way to register ParentClass via StructureMap so that it resolves with an `IDependency` that is the same instance between `ParentClass` and `IChildClass`?

**Edit**

To clarify, I'm looking to resolve `ParentClass` as if it had been manually created like this (from MrFox's answer):

```
IDependency dependency = new Dependency();
ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass(dependency);
ParentClass parentClass = new ParentClass(childClass, dependency);
```

`IDependency` should **not** be a singleton.  I want to resolve `ParentClass` with a different `IDependency` every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code here will give you the same IDependency for Parent and child.

```
var container = new Container(x => {
            x.For<IChildClass>().Use<ChildClass>();
            x.For<IDependency>().Use<Dependency>();
        });

var firstParent = container.GetInstance<ParentClass>();
```

If you where to ask for another `container.GetInstance<ParentClass>();` it will give you a new parent, child and dependency. If you would like to have IDependency as a singelton so it will be used everytime you ask for a Parent or child class, then you can register it with the Singeleton method: `x.For<IDependency>().Singleton().Use<Dependency>();`

Comment: I'm looking to be able to create a `ParentClass` with a `ChildClass` that both share the _same_ `IDependency`.  You're example creates a `ParentClass` with one instance of `IDependency` and `ChildClass` with another instance of `IDependency`.  I don't want `IDependency` to be a singleton either.  When separate instances of `ParentClass` are created, they should have different `IDependency`'s.  I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: The example I provided here will have the same IDependency for the ParentClass and the ChildClass passed in to ParentClass constructor. Structuremap uses an PerRequest lifecycle and not a Transient lifecycle as most IoC use.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer whether StructureMap can do this.  But using a factory to create the child from within the parent gives you an IoC-container-agnostic solution.

```
public interface IChildFactory {
  IChild Create(IDependency dependency);
}

public class ParentClass
{
  private readonly IChildClass _child;

  public ParentClass(IChildFactory childFactory, IDependency dependency)
  {
    _child = childFactory.Create(dependency);
  }
}

class ChildFactory : IChildFactory 
{
  IChildClass Create(IDependency dependency)
  {
    return new ChildClass(dependency);
  }
}
```

Now all `IChild` instances would be created by this simple factory instead of through the IoC container.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a reference of one IDependency object to both constructors:

```
IDependency dependency = new Dependency();
ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass(dependency);
ParentClass parentClass = new ParentClass(childClass, dependency);
```

Comment: I'm looking for how to setup StructureMap to resolve a ParentClass like this.  So a call to `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ParentClass>()` would return a `ParentClass` in the same manner as you manually did.